# Multiple ajax calls on every call update the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-audio

On my page I have an ajax script which has a chain of ajax calls nested inside each other's success function so that the next one executes. For example --

```
            $.ajax({
                data: {
                    action: 'polly_pros',
                    pollytext: text
                },
                type: 'post',
                url: polpro.ajax_url,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#player')[0].pause();
                    $('#player')[0].load();
                    var aud_dur = $('#aud_dur').val();
              // NEXT AJAX CALL                  
                    $.ajax({
                        data: {
```

On my form my hidden input --

```
<input type="hidden" name="aud_dur" id="aud_dur" value="" />
```

On my page to update my hidden input of the audio file whenever it is loaded, I use --

```
var Aud = $('#player');
var aud_dur = $('#aud_dur');
Aud[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    aud_dur.val($('#player')[0].duration);
});
```

On my php script I'm trying to retrieve the value as so --

```
$aud_dur = $_POST['aud_dur'];
```

My hidden input updates fine on my form but the new value is not being sent back so that I can use it with the very next ajax call. Right now there doesn't seem to be any data being sent from the variable.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

My ajax code has several calls in it that are executed upon the success of the previous one.

The polly_pros ajax call creates an audio file and the following ajax call is suppose to get the audio duration from there, which I am also putting in a hidden input.

I can get the duration if the file is already there but if creating the file dynamically (like I need to do) I am unable to get the duration value.

This is my full ajax code (unrelated variables deleted to simplify) ---

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#make-vid', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var aud_dur;
    var pollytext = $('#pollytext').val();
    var path = $('#path').val();
    var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
    // AJAX CALL
    $.ajax({
        url: vformpro.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'vform_pros',
            post_id: post_id,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var audio = $("#player");
            var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
            var aud_dur = $("#aud_dur").val();
            var tune_dur = $("#tune_dur").val();

            // AJAX CALL
            $.ajax({
                data: {
                    action: 'polly_pros',
                    post_id: post_id
                },
                type: 'post',
                url: polpro.ajax_url,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#player')[0].pause();
                    $('#player')[0].load(function() {

                        // HERE I AM TRYING TO GET THE AUDIO DURATION UPON SUCCESS OF THIS AJAX CALL SO // THAT I CAN PASS IT TO THE FOLLOWING AJAX CALL

                        var Aud = $('#player');
                        var aud_dur = $('#aud_dur');
                        Aud[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
                            aud_dur.val($('#player')[0].duration);
                            console.log(aud_dur);
                        });

                    });
                    // AJAX CALL
                    $.ajax({
                        data: {
                            action: 'mvid_pros',
                            post_id: post_id,
                            aud_dur: aud_dur,
                            tune_dur: tune_dur
                        },
                        type: 'post',
                        url: mvidpro.ajax_url,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $("#video-preview")[0].pause();
                            $("#video-preview")[0].load();
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $('.load-text').text('Error on making Video.');
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a [link to the full code](https://pastebin.com/PZAtgkkk) (WIP) to give better context to my question.

Comment: Your second ajax call starts before the loadeddata event of your player, so the line `var aud_dur = $('#aud_dur').val();` get the previous value. Try to place `var aud_dur = $('#aud_dur').val();` and your second ajax call inside the loaddeddata event handler.

Comment: When you call the Ajax call JS would run immediately before assigning the value to the hidden varialbe in HTML. There is one way if you want to add settimeout(1000, passtheAJAXfunction(aud_val)) of one second before calling the next ajax call and write the ajax call function seperately and call it in the success of the first ajax call.

Comment: @vbRocks please see my updated question

Comment: whoever voted my question down, should at least explain why.

Comment: @Rich while I didn't down vote it, most JavaScript developers consider this to be a very newbie problem and a JavaScript Anti-pattern to have "callback hell" The solution for it is usually to use defined functions or, if you can, use promises which linerize async calls.

Comment: well then I would guess i came to the right place to learn, no? im definitely not a JS developer and this is the first time I ever had to run ajax calls one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Updated answer)*

I still believe that the main problem is likely with `$('#player')[0].load(function() {...})` that you have as in [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/PZAtgkkk) code.

I mean, if the element with the `id` of `player` is an `audio` element, then the `function` you provided to the `load()` method of that `audio` element would never get called. And note that `$(selector).load()` is different from `$(selector)[0].load()` — the 'selector' can be `'#my_id'`, `'.my_class'`, etc.

But anyway, please try [this](https://pastebin.com/xcVBu5fG) code which is an *optimized* version of the *full* version of [your](https://pastebin.com/raw/PZAtgkkk) code.

You may not be able to simply compare your code with the optimized version; however, it shouldn't be too hard for you to spot the major changes such as I used a single `form_data` object instead of numerous variables, where `form_data` stores the form data that you send to your PHP script.

And in the optimized code, you'll find this code which performs the third AJAX request (with the action `mvid_pros`):

```
function mvidPros() {
  var aud_dur = $('#player')[0].duration;
  console.log(aud_dur);

  // Set the value of the #aud_dur field.
  $("#aud_dur").val(aud_dur);

  // Initialize the data for the 'mvid_pros' AJAX call.
  var form_data = {
    action: 'mvid_pros',
    post_id: $("#post_id").val()
  };

  // Add input values to the data.
  form_data.songlink = $("#songlink").val();
  ...
  form_data.aud_dur = aud_dur;
  form_data.tune_dur = $("#tune_dur").val();
  ...

  $.ajax({
    'data': form_data,
    type: 'post',
    url: mvidpro.ajax_url,
    cache: false,
    //async:false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      ...
    },
    error: function() {
      $('.load-text').text('Error on making Video.');
    }
  });
}
```

And here's the code that calls the above function:

```
$('#player')[0].pause();
$('#player').one('loadeddata', mvidPros);
$('#player')[0].load();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. However it still is not passing the correct variable to my php function, instead it is passing the previous value. The hidden input on my form for #aud_dur always gets updated with the correct value though, but that value doesnt get passed to my php function. If I do not create a new audio file and the duration stays the same, then the correct value gets passed.

Comment: also placing `console.log(aud_dur);` after your suggested code but before my next ajax call, shows this in the console `n.fn.init [input#aud_dur, context: document, selector: "#aud_dur"]`

Comment: Can you post the new code (the full version of your code but with the replacement code I suggested in my answer) on Pastebin? I'd like to see it, and what PHP library you use for the TTS functionality?

Comment: `https://pastebin.com/mEZ1zYfG` and I used wordpress with the latest php version installed on plesk.

Comment: Never mind about the plugin. I think I may have seen where the problem is. I'll try to fix that problem and be back later.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can also check [this](https://pastebin.com/86PYkgBQ) and compare it with [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/PZAtgkkk) to see what changed.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now it seems that the hidden input field doesnt update at all without having to reload the page. Before, the input field would at least always update. Also, now I can see the number being printed in the console log, even though its the wrong/previous number.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Hopefully it will help you, even if it may not exactly answer the question.

Comment: wow thanks! I tried your code out and so far it seems to be working. I have to test it some more to make sure, but so far so good. You've been very helpful thus far!

Comment: Sure, take your time. =)

Comment: would it possible to chime in on another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049893/create-image-from-text-using-form-and-save-to-server

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your `aud_dur` value in your post data to the server. The form submit method isn't being called, you are doing an ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        action: 'polly_pros',
        pollytext: text,
        aud_dur : $('#aud_dur').val()
    },
.....
```

Change your data object to that to include it in your post values and you should see it being sent to your server. You can check what is actually sent by inspecting the network request in your browser's dev console.

Per your updated question, your next Ajax call is running before your aud_dur value is being assigned. Put your Ajax call inside the event handler after you assign the aud_dur variable

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#make-vid', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var aud_dur;
    var pollytext = $('#pollytext').val();
    var path = $('#path').val();
    var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
    // AJAX CALL
    $.ajax({
        url: vformpro.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'vform_pros',
            post_id: post_id,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var audio = $("#player");
            var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
            var aud_dur = $("#aud_dur").val();
            var tune_dur = $("#tune_dur").val();

            // AJAX CALL
            $.ajax({
                data: {
                    action: 'polly_pros',
                    post_id: post_id
                },
                type: 'post',
                url: polpro.ajax_url,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#player')[0].pause();
                    $('#player')[0].load(function() {

                        // HERE I AM TRYING TO GET THE AUDIO DURATION UPON SUCCESS OF THIS AJAX CALL SO // THAT I CAN PASS IT TO THE FOLLOWING AJAX CALL

                        var Aud = $('#player');
                        var aud_dur = $('#aud_dur');
                        Aud[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
                            aud_dur.val($('#player')[0].duration);
                            console.log(aud_dur);
                            // AJAX CALL **MOVED**
                            $.ajax({
                                data: {
                                    action: 'mvid_pros',
                                    post_id: post_id,
                                    aud_dur: $('#aud_dur').val(),
                                    tune_dur: tune_dur
                                },
                                type: 'post',
                                url: mvidpro.ajax_url,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    $("#video-preview")[0].pause();
                                    $("#video-preview")[0].load();
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    $('.load-text').text('Error on making Video.');
                                }
                            });
                        });

                    });


                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the audio duration value needs to be passed into my next ajax call to my php function

Comment: can you provide an example? the first example seems incorrect since I need the audio duration after the polly pro ajax success

Comment: @Rich updated. your event handler isn't being triggered before you are sending your next AJAX request. So the aud_dur value isn't being set before it is being used so it was passed as null.

Comment: ive tried your suggestion but after the polly_pros call, it gets stuck and continues showing the loading gif and text.

Comment: @Rich, I fixed one issue, but you're going to need to look in the console etc and find and post any errors that are occurring otherwise we aren't going to know what is going on. Otherwise you'll need to provide a working codepen or something that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Also I posted my full code in my edited question. As far as the console, I always check, but when the code got stuck like I mentioned, there was no output to the console.

Comment: It's likely a failing webrequest you'd see in the network tab. If it still doesn't work, implement it in codepen.io and link it, then we can actually see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with your code, properly refactor your code and you should be fine:

P.S: I wasn't able to run the code so please make sure you properly scope your variables in order for code to work properly.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#make-vid', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pollytext = $('#pollytext').val();
    var path = $('#path').val();
    var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
    var onAudioDataLoaded = function() {
        var aud_duration = $('#player')[0].duration;
        var tune_duration = $("#tune_dur").val();
        $('#aud_dur').val(duration);

        // AJAX CALL
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                action: 'mvid_pros',
                post_id: post_id,
                aud_dur: aud_duration,
                tune_dur: tune_duration
            },
            type: 'post',
            url: mvidpro.ajax_url,
            cache: false,
            success: onMvidProsSuccess,
            error: onMvidProsError
        });
    };
    var onMvidProsSuccess = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#video-preview")[0].pause();
        $("#video-preview")[0].load();
    };
    var onMvidProsError = function() {
        $('.load-text').text('Error on making Video.');
    };
    var onPolyProsError = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    };
    var onPolyProsSuccess = function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        $('#player')[0].pause();
        $('#player')[0].load(function() {

            // HERE I AM TRYING TO GET THE AUDIO DURATION UPON SUCCESS OF THIS AJAX CALL SO // THAT I CAN PASS IT TO THE FOLLOWING AJAX CALL

            var Aud = $('#player');
            Aud[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', onAudioDataLoaded);
        });
    };
    var onFormPostSuccess = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // AJAX CALL
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                action: 'polly_pros',
                post_id: post_id
            },
            type: 'post',
            url: polpro.ajax_url,
            cache: false,
            success: onPolyProsSuccess,
            error: onPolyProsError
        });
    };
    // AJAX CALL
    $.ajax({
        url: vformpro.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'vform_pros',
            post_id: post_id,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: onFormPostSuccess
    });
});
```

Comment: the ajax calls are suppose to be in the following order --- 1. vform_pros 2. polly_pros 3. mvid_pros .. im not familiar with how your code is set up, so my question is does it execute in that order?

Comment: It is executing in the same order as your posted code.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but after the polly_pro call, it gets stuck and doesnt move forward to the next call.

Comment: Do you see any error/logs on console. On success it calls `onPolyProsSuccess` function, so if it gets stuck the problem could be code within that function.

Comment: I dont see any errors shown on the console. I know it's getting stuck at pollypro success cause the 'success console.log'  comes from that function.

Comment: Then I bet you problem is within `$('#player')[0].load` call.

Comment: what do you mean? any suggestions?

Comment: @Rich https://api.jquery.com/load-event/, may be load has issue it self, so you should verify if `load` event is being fired and working correctly.