# Create image from text using form and save to server

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, image

I am trying to use a php function on my page to create an image from a text input. But nothing seems to be happening. This is my current code -

Php -

```
$to = $paths. '/card.png';

if (isset($_POST['make_pic'])) {
$text = $_POST['txt_input'];
$im = imagecreate(200, 80);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

imagestring($im, 4, 30, 25, $text, $textcolor);

ob_start();
imagepng($im);
$data = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($to,$data);
imagedestroy($im);
}
```

HTML -

```
<form name="picform" id="picform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="txt_input" maxlength="50">
<input type="submit" id="make_pic" name="make_pic" value="Convert">
</form>
```

The form doesn't have a action cause I'm using ajax -

```
$("#make_pic").click(function() {
    $('#picform').ajaxForm();
});
```

**UPDATE**

I am trying to get one image placed on top of the image I created, thus creating one final image. This is my current code, which works for creating the image but not placing the overlay image ---

```
$paths = "/uploads/". $current_user->ID."/".$v_Id;
$assets = "/uploads/assets";

$to = $paths. '/contact_card.png';

// Text from form to be used
$c_name1 = $_POST['c_name'];
$c_biz1 = $_POST['c_biz'];
$c_num = $_POST['c_num'];
$c_mail1 = $_POST['c_email'];

$c_name = strtoupper($c_name1);
$c_biz = strtoupper($c_biz1);
$c_mail = strtoupper($c_mail1);


$headliner = "Contact Info\r\n";

$text = $headliner."\r\n".$c_name."\r\n".$c_biz."\r\n".$c_num."\r\n".$c_mail;

$im = imagecreate(1280, 720);
$im2 = $paths. '/profile_pic.png';

// Black background
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// Text Colors
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

// Font text options
$font = $assets.'/fonts/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf';
$font_size = 24;
$angle = 45;

// Get image Width and Height
$image_width = imagesx($im);  
$image_height = imagesy($im);

// Get Bounding Box Size
$text_box = imagettfbbox($font_size,$angle,$font,$text);

// Get your Text Width and Height
$text_width = $text_box[2]-$text_box[0];
$text_height = $text_box[7]-$text_box[1];

// Calculate coordinates of the text
$x = 440;
$y = 260;

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $white, $font, $text);

// HERE I AM TRYING TO PLACE A PICTURE LEFT CENTERED ON TOP OF THE OTHER PICTURE
imagecopymerge($im, $im2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 100);


// Create the image and save to server
ob_start();
imagepng($im);
$data = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($to,$data);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP part actually works for me, though this could be replaced:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($im);
$data = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($to,$data);
imagedestroy($im);
```

with this:

```
imagepng($im, $to);
imagedestroy($im);
```

But I'm not positive if that's the issue, since your existing code worked for me. So try checking if the `$paths` is a valid directory?

### UPDATE

> nothing seems to be happening

Could it be because you didn't `echo` (or output something) after the image is created? Well I mean, the image may have been successfully (re-)created, but your PHP/JS script doesn't "tell" you of the status; hence you see "nothing". Try `echo`-ing something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['make_pic'])) {
  ...
  imagedestroy($im);

  echo 'Success!';
}
```

And then use this JS:

```
$('#picform').ajaxForm({
  success: function(res){
    alert(res);
  }
});
```

*(Update #2: I intentionally removed the "Additional Note" part, but you can always see the answer's [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52068050/revisions) to find that part.)*

Comment: i dont have a problem with the ajax though, its my php function not working I believe

Comment: @Rich did the answer help you? If not, perhaps you can check the `error_log` file, inspect the XHR/AJAX/network tab and check any issues, or include (in your *question*) the full PHP (and JS) code you use.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, but can you tell us which part of my answer that (helped you) solved the problem? I'm sure it'd be helpful to other users as well.

Comment: It was a mistake on my end with my `$paths` that you had pointed out in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Rich. I did think of that in the first place before I wrote my answer, but I guess I was too much concerned about the "proper `ajaxForm()` usage". Apologies for that. =) Cheers!

Comment: lol it ok thanks though. One more question, I am trying to add an image to the one i created. I've updated my question with my current code.

Comment: Do you still need help with the overlay image?

Comment: yes please. I am trying to overlay a profile image to the left of my current image, similar to a business card.